# Cordova - add platform

Tags: android, cordova

Desarrolle una pequeña aplicacion para cordova, pero al momento de add la platform me aparece el siguiente error. no se si estoy omitiendo algo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si continuo con el cordova build me aparece esto(lo cual me imagino que es por el error anterior)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debrías checar con que versión de android estas haciendo tu proyecto y ver la versión de plataforma que tienes instalada ya sea en tu simulador del pc o smartphone.
Checa este enlace y prueba con el ejemplo que viene para probar que hayas instalado bien Cordova -> [Create your first Cordova app](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)

Comment: El error que te aparece es que ya tienes añadida la plataforma de android cuando la quieres añadir y el siguiente error es que falta el fichero de la API. Prueba a quitar la plataforma con `cordova platform remove android` y volver a añadirla `cordova platform add android` y coméntanos qué pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Solucione mi problema de esta forma:

Elimine la plataforma anterior

```
cordova platform rm android
```

luego,  agrege la plataforma

```
cordova platform add android
```

para finalizar solo ejecute este comando

```
cordova build android
```

*La diferencia en esta parte fue que no habia colocado anteriormente android al final*

Al finalizar mi apk fue creada correctamente.